# How to determine if the value of a bound text box is different than the value of an unbound text box?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently have a bound text box, lets call this 'shift1'.

I also have two unbound text boxes that show values from a table upon form_ load event. These are called 'ucontrol' (which is a negative number) and 'lcontrol' (which is a positive number).

I need to determine a way to say 
If 'shift1' is less than 'ucontrol' OR greater than 'lcontrol' then if true 'total count' (bound text box) is 1.

The problem is that when running the code, it is always saying the value is true, meaning it always is a 1.

So if the value of 'shift1' is between 'ucontrol' and 'lcontrol' the 'total count' should equal 0 or false.

Currently, I have tried countless things and I believe the conclusion is 'ucontrol' and 'lcontrol' are unbound and I am trying to compare them to 'shift1' which is a bound text box.

The unbound and the bound are both numbers and the total count is an integer.

Here is what I currently have, I have tried other things but decided to stick with a very simple statement determining whether it is true or false:

```
    If shift1.value < ucontrol.value Then
        [total count].Value = 1
    ElseIf shift1.value >= ucontrol.value then
        [total count].Value = 0
    End If
```

I would like to get code that reads something along the lines of this:

```
    If shift1.value < ucontrol.value OR shift1.value > lcontrol.value Then
        [total count].Value = 1
    ElseIf shift1.value is betweeen the ucontrol.value and lcontrol.value 
        [total count].value = 0 
    End If
```

I am expecting it to find out when something is false, currently, it says everything is true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like something wrong with data in controls. Try to copy the data from text boxes to numeric variables and check the values of those variables, it will show the difference. The `.Value` property may return a string instead of expected numeric value.

Comment: What event is this code in?

Comment: @June7 This event is on my save_record event.

Comment: There is no 'save record' event. Do you mean a 'Save' button Click event? Have you step debugged?

Answer (score 0):

Bound or unbound should not matter.

Remove "is" and "the" and second code you show should work but can simplify. Following works for me:

```
With Me
.TotalCount = IIf(.shift1 < .ucontrol Or .shift1 >= .lcontrol, 1, 0)
End With
```

Assumes ucontrol, lcontrol, shift1 are not null.

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that 'Unbound' textboxes are still read as text (even during vba).

That is why shift1.value < ucontrol.value never equal each other. shift1.value is a number. and ucontrol.value is a text.

To convert to all numbers try the following:

```
[total count].value = 0
shift1 = shift1 + 0
ucontrol = ucontrol + 0
lcontrol = lcontrol + 0

If shift1.value > ucontrol.value or shift1.value < lcontrol.value then
    [total count].value = 1
else
    [total count].value = 0
End If
```

Adding (+ 0) to each text box name will convert them into a number, especially when using Unbound text boxes.

Hope this helps. I've seen this issue before.